# "Unread Message in your inbox" Notification not refreshes till page refresh

Tags: bug, global-inbox, google-chrome, back-button

I am using Google Chrome. There are multiple tabs of Stack Overflow are open.
When there is any message arrives in Inbox then it appears at top left corner of every tab.
What I did is right-clicked on message and selected open in new tab. And then for hiding inbox popup I clicked outside the box. Then I went to any link/webpage. Then clicked on back button which Chrome has at top left corner. What I see is there is again same message appearing in inbox. To get actual result of inbox need to do refresh or click on any link within site.

Actually whenever I move to Stack Overflow page it should recheck for any message arrived and not use buffer data.

Comment: Same thing happened with me too, today

Comment: You mean real time notification count update.. Sounds reasonable enough..

Comment: I Don't want more frequent data, But I also Don't want the Wrong notification.

Comment: I want an unread **Massage** :(

Comment: If we open a page in new tab we can't go back from page.

Comment: @hims056 : Go to Beck page from page where actually notification arrived and Right Clicked on that.

Comment: Can you please reformat this with a lot less use of **bold**. I tried but I was started to get worried that I was removing some of your question.

Comment: @Mansfield : Have u got an Unread **Message**? :)

Comment: Using the back button is not really good practice as far as I can tell. What happens is that JavaScript code is being executed when there is new message, so when getting Back to the page it's re-executed by the browser as it's trying to emulate the exact state of the page as it was when you left it. So in my opinion, this is not a bug. You get back to the page and see it the way it was when leaving it.